# Permission of root-owned folder

Tags: permissions

When I create a directory as a root user with permission 777, then I can delete it when I am logged in as default user but when I logged in as `a` or `b` user, I can't able to delete it. It's showing permission denied.

My question is, why can my default user delete that folder created by root and why other users can't, tough all are having 777 permission.

Comment: Do those users have write permission to the parent directory of the one with `777` permissions?

Comment: The ability to delete a file or directory mainly depends on the permissions and ownership of the directory where the directory or file is located.  If a user owns a directory `dir`, and has write permissions in it, they would be able to delete files in it that belongs to other users.

Comment: no, I don't know. But root gave 777 permission. so anyone can delete it right? then why only default user?

Comment: #Kusalananda
But root created that directory then no one can delete it other than root, then why my default user can delete it.

Comment: @SubirMakur If that user owns the directory in which the subdirectory owned by root was created, the user can delete the root-owned subdirectory. It has nothing to do with the ownership nor permissions on the subdirectory.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has write and execute permissions on a directory, they can delete any file or directory therein, regardless of the ownerships of those.  It is so because the deletion of a file or subdirectory from a directory is a modification to the directory, not to the thing being deleted.

Example: I create a directory owned by root in a directory that I own, then delete it.

```
$ sudo mkdir directory
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  512 Nov 25 11:11 directory
```

```
$ rmdir directory
$ ls -l
```

(no output)

Now, if the subdirectory *contains files*, then the permissions on that directory becomes more interesting:

```
$ sudo mkdir directory
$ sudo touch directory/file
```

```
$ rm -rf directory
rm: directory/file: Permission denied
rm: directory: Directory not empty
```

Here, I can't delete the subdirectory because I have no permissions to delete the file that is inside it.

But you say that the permissions are set to `777`, which means anyone could delete the files inside it:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 directory
$ rm -rf directory
```

(no error)

Another user on my system would still not be able to do this, because they have no write permissions in the directory where I'm working, although they *could* still delete the *contents* of the root-owned subdirectory, if that directory was accessible to them (the users would need execute permissions on the directory and *all parent directories*).